# Filtering query String MongoDB

Tags: database, string, filter, get

I am trying to filter my dataBS from MongoDB for that I have created the following route

route.get("/", getFilterRecipe);

with the following function

export async function  getFilterRecipe (req, res) {
try {

```
const { type, mealtime, preparationtime, difficulty, opinion } = req.query;

const filter = {};
if (type) filter.type = type;
if (mealtime) filter.mealtime = mealtime;
if (preparationtime) filter.preparationtime = preparationtime;
if (difficulty) filter.difficulty = difficulty;
if (opinion) filter.opinion = opinion;

const recipes = await Recipe.find(filter);


res.json(recipes);
```

} catch (err) {

```
console.error('Error:', err);
res.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
```

}
};

nontheless when I try to filter the url for instance https://l4rnrz4l-4000.asse.devtunnels.ms/api/recipe?type=american&mealtime=lunch. I get back all the recipes rather than the filter ones.

Obviously I am doing something wrong but what is it?

Thanks for your time and help.

I have tried to parse the res.query and it doesn't work.
To be honest dont really know what to do. Chat GPT is not helping me out either.